# Java access to lib

Tags: java, mtp

I'm trying to develop a java app based in the lib jusbpmp. it's a java mtp lib to connect to android device over usb.

I have added jusbpmp-0.1.5.jar file in my project. It appears in the Libraries folder on my Java project under Netbean.

I have started a class to connect to the device but the import seems not working.

```
import jpmp.manager;        

/**
 *
 * @author seb
 */
public class MTPAbstract {

    static boolean isConnected(String filterProductName, String filterProductid, String filterVendorid){
        try {

            DeviceManager dm;
            dm = DeviceManager.getInstance();
```

DeviceManager is not resolved. import done is based on the package name in the DeviceManager class defined inside the jusbpmp lib.

Project screenshot

[image]

Any idea ?

Thax

Comment: Is `DeviceManager` is in the same package as `MTPAbstract`?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot for your Netbeans Project.

Comment: @Karthikeyan the DeviceManager is declared in the jpmp.manager this is why I need the import working

Comment: @The Well it's done :-)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a class, you need to specify the fully qualified name. That is, the name of the package the class is in and the name of the class itself. Assuming `DeviceManager` is in the package `jpmp.manager`, the import has to be

```
import jpmp.manager.DeviceManager;
```